# Grep unix time range gives invalid range error

Tags: grep

I need to grep this time range: `2020-04-27T20:29:27 - 2020-04-27T20:3x (any time after 30)`

However this grep gives me an invalid time range error:

```
egrep MESSAGE_SENT company-runtime-cdrs*.log | grep '27T19:[29-30]' | wc -l
grep: Invalid range end
0
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `Invalid range end` is not "invalid time range". It has nothing to do with time. In your command `[29-30]` means "`2` or `0` or any character from the range from `9` to `3`". The range is invalid because `3` comes *before* `9` (formally this is locale-dependent; I expect `3` to come before `9` in most locales). `[23-90]` would probably be valid, equivalent to `[023456789]`. Neither form is what you want to match, I guess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148240/10765659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to match minutes `29` and `30`.

## why your expression does not work

`[29-30]` does not do what you want from it; it means

> `2` or (any character from the range from `9` to `3`) or `0`.

The range is indeed invalid because `3` comes before `9` (*).

---

## how to do it

To achieve what you want (i.e. matching `29` and `30`), you can simply use `(29|30)` in your regex, like

```
grep MESSAGE_SENT company-runtime-cdrs*.log | grep '27T20:\(29\|30\)'
```

or

```
egrep MESSAGE_SENT company-runtime-cdrs*.log | egrep '27T20:(29|30)'
```

(note that `egrep` needs less escaping so it is more readable)

### your exact time range

> I need to grep this time range: `2020-04-27T20:29:27 - 2020-04-27T20:3x (any time after 30)`

this is a bit more complicated:

```
grep MESSAGE_SENT company-runtime-cdrs*.log | grep '27T20:\(29:\(2[7-9]\|[3-5].\)\|3.:\)'
```

or

```
egrep MESSAGE_SENT company-runtime-cdrs*.log | egrep '27T20:(29:(2[7-9]|[3-5].)|3.:..)'
```

---

## further advice

I suggest to use a tool like [regexr](https://regexr.com) to test / explain your regexen. [I used it too to check what I came up with above](https://regexr.com/61dvd).

(*) formally this is locale-dependent, but I have yet to see a locale where it is not true

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you so much!